# Arduino - Separate the integer of the String in Serial.ReadString()

Tags: regex, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm starting with Arduino programming, and I'm developing a program that will receive an string and a integer, together, for example: "pisca 10". How can I separate it in a String(pisca) and a integer(10) variable? The integer will be applied in a For() loop and the String will be tested with another. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do it in two steps:

1. Read the complete string (which is "picsa 10" in your example) and store it into a variable as a String.
2. Extract the number part from the stored string.

For `2`, you can implement this yourself as an exercise, but you can also use [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) function which purpose is to parse a string according to a format. Please see the example in the linked page.